# Escaping in ERB Form Generator

Tags: ruby, escaping, sinatra, erb

I'm trying to iterate through an array of which each entry will create an input field in a form made in ERB.  I've set up a @loopcount integer that gets increased for every new entry in this array.  I would like to use that increasing integer in fieldnames:

```
Item <input name="s_fieldname_<%= @loopcount %>" id="s_fieldname_<%= @loopcount %>" type="text" value="<%= field[0] %>" size="12"><br/>
```

Because of being inside the double quotations, that @loopcount is not taking.  I'm guessing this is an escaping issue of some sort.  %% did not work.

Edit: Add syntax

```
    <% @fields.each do |field| %>
        <span class="red"><%= field[0] %></span> - <%= field[1] %><br>
        <strong>fieldname</strong> <input name="s_fieldname_#{@loopcount}" type="text" value="<%= field[0] %>" size="12"><br/>
        <strong>show</strong> <input name="s_show_#{@loopcount}" type="checkbox" checked><br/>
        <strong>required</strong> <input name="s_required_#{@loopcount}" type="checkbox"><br/>
        <strong>description</strong> <input name="s_description_#{@loopcount}" type="text" value="" size="60"><br/>
        <% @loopcount += 1 %>
    <% end %>
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?  Cheers

Comment: Have you tried string interpolation, i.e: `"s_fieldname_#{@loopcount}"`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either.  I had not tried it though.

Comment: may be it will help if you show us your loop code as well

Comment: Syntax added.  Started in app.rb with @loopcount = 1.  The loop works, the loopcount variable I can't seem to get inserted into that form syntax.

Comment: Your new code doesn’t match the old. It looks like you’ve added the version using `"s_fieldname_#{@loopcount}"` rather than `"s_fieldname_<%= @loopcount %>"`.

Comment: Yes that's because I've been trying various ways of getting this done.  Nothing has worked, neither of these versions.  I'm aware they are different.

Comment: What do you mean by “@loopcount is not taking”? This works fine for me (using the original ERb syntax) providing I initialise `@loopcount` first.

Comment: I am getting this:  <input name="s_type_#{@loopcount}" type="radio" value="text" checked="checked">

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how this happened, but the first syntax now works upon replacement.

```
...name="s_fieldname_<%= @loopcount %>" type="text" value="<%= field[0] %>"...
```

I'm using Chrome for this, but Safari was also showing the same syntax result.